# Can i Use own Facebook App ID with this Social Comment Plugin?

Tags: comments, social-sharing

Is it possible to connect the plugin with an own Facebook App ID?

In this way it would be entirely clear that this App belongs to the respective blog.

Beyond that, if I have other Facebook stuff on the blog, which requires a Facebook Connect, the user only has to authenticate once with one app. So in this way an app could handle all the Facebook stuff that happend on the blog.

To Alex an his Team: Just a great piece of work! This plugin is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for sharing it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/